# Template strings in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm running into a strange issue while trying to use template strings (``) in TypeScript. For some reason, I'm not able to enter new lines or line breaks. I've tried a variety of things, including:

1. Simply going to the next line of the template string
2. Adding `<br>` html tag
3. Switching from template strings to regular strings that include \n

My environment:

- IDE: Visual Studio 2015
- Application: A Chrome Extension
- Languages: TypeScript/JavaScript

Sample code:

```
const template = `<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3"> ${fileName} </td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
${commands.map((cmd) => `
<tr>${cmd.target}</tr>
<tr>${cmd.value}</tr>
`)}
</tbody>
</table>`
```

This issue is a bit frustrating because when I try to do something very similar in a JavaScript repl, it works perfectly fine like so:

https://repl.it/EMMh

### UPDATE

I have figured out the solution to my issue but one of the comments mentioned that I forgot to include the context within my question. To clarify, I am building a feature in my Chrome Extension application that will allow the user to save a given file as HTML. The snippet above with the template strings actually works perfectly fine. In my particular scenario, the issue occurs when I was improperly using the Chrome.Downloads API. Essentially, the API was expecting an encoded URI component and I failed to do that.

Comment: Not quite enough here to go on. Where are you not seeing the line breaks? Can you post an example of the output of the program, as well as the relevant section of the javascript output from the TypeScript transpiler?

Comment: The example you posted seems to have backticks inside the template, causing a SyntaxError. Am I seeing this right?

Comment: This code works perfectly fine on the typescript repl.

Comment: @slezica that shouldn't be a SyntaxError, it's perfectly valid to have them as long as they're within the `${}`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. It compiles and a `console.log(template)` shows me html with newlines. How are you testing?

Comment: Hello everyone, I apologize for the late response as I wasn't able to look at this until now. 

In response:

@YonaAppletree - Sorry!, I should have added some more context to the question. The idea is to allow my user to download an HTML via chrome.downloads API. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

It turns out that the issue wasn't with the template strings but the way Chrome.downloads() parses the template.